# flask-sqlalchemy multiple relationship between two tables

Tags: database, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy, relational-database

I have 3 user type in my flask application

- Admin
- Agent
- Customer

The idea is to store all necessary information of a user in `User` table and build relationship in another table with extra fields like `Customer` or `Agent` table.

As an agent can refer multiple customer (Agent can share his refer link, each user will signup with that link will count for that Agent).

```py
from flask import current_app

from datetime import datetime
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer as Serializer
from application import db
from application import login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


########## START USER ####################
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    profile_picture = db.Column(db.String(20), default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60))
    user_role = db.Column(db.String(60), default="user")
    join_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    ip = db.Column(db.String(60))
    recent_ip = db.Column(db.String(60))
    details = db.relationship('UserDetails', backref='user', uselist=False)
    # ACCOUNT ACTIVATION
    activation_token = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    # USER STATUS 
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)

    # GENERATE ACTIVATION TOKEN
    def generate_activation_token(self, expires_sec=3600):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

     #   GENERATING PASSWORD RESET TOKEN
    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    #  verify the token if the token has exprired or invalid
    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    
    #  verify the token if the token has exprired or invalid
    @staticmethod
    def verify_activation_token(token):
        s = Serializer(current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)
########## END USER ####################


########## START USER DETAILS ####################
class UserDetails(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_details'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(200))
    telegram = db.Column(db.String(200))
    whatsapp = db.Column(db.String(200))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
########## END USER DETAILS ####################


########## START AGENT ####################
class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    total_deposit = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    total_balance = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    total_withdraw = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    is_superagent  = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=False)
    agent_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys='Agent.agent_user_id', backref='agent', lazy=True)
########## END AGENT ####################
    

########## START AGENT ####################
class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    total_deposit = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    total_balance = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    total_withdraw = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    
    customer_referred_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('agent.id'))
    referred_by = db.relationship('Agent', foreign_keys='Customer.customer_referred_by_id', backref='referred_customers', lazy=True)
    
    customer_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys='Customer.customer_user_id', backref='customer', lazy=True)
########## END AGENT ####################
```

### Issue:

when I try to run `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade` then I get the error in terminal

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: user_id
[SQL: ALTER TABLE agent ADD COLUMN user_id INTEGER]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

First off, I try to use `user_id` and `user` in each table. when I get error. I thought it because of same name. after changing the column name like `customer_user_id` and others I am getting error `duplicate column name: user_id`

### Question

What is the best idea for customer table to relation with agent? relation with `Agent` table or `User` table? and how it could be done?